# Sorting, rounding and removing duplicates in a list of time stamps using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to process some data based on their time stamps. I have a working solution, but I feel that it could be expressed in a much cleaner way using LINQ.

I need to do the following:

1. Sort the list, based on the timestamp
2. Round off the milliseconds
3. Remove any duplicate values (does not matter which is removed)

Here is my current working solution:

```
using MoreLinq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SortingWITSMLRealTimeSignals
{
    class Program
    {
        class Foo
        {
            public DateTime TimeStampUtc;
            public int SomeData;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Foo> testData = new List<Foo> { 
                new Foo { TimeStampUtc = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 20, 20, 23, 515), SomeData = 42 },
                new Foo { TimeStampUtc = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 20, 20, 24, 515), SomeData = 42 },
                new Foo { TimeStampUtc = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 20, 20, 25, 515), SomeData = 42 },
                new Foo { TimeStampUtc = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 20, 20, 25, 245), SomeData = 33 },
                new Foo { TimeStampUtc = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 20, 20, 27, 515), SomeData = 42 },
                new Foo { TimeStampUtc = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 20, 20, 28, 515), SomeData = 42 },
            };

            List<Foo> orderedTestData = testData.OrderBy(rs => rs.TimeStampUtc).ToList();

            List<Foo> roundedTestData = new List<Foo>();
            foreach (var otd in orderedTestData)
            {
                otd.TimeStampUtc = otd.TimeStampUtc.AddMilliseconds(-otd.TimeStampUtc.Millisecond);
                roundedTestData.Add(otd);
            }

            var filteredTestData = roundedTestData.DistinctBy(x => x.TimeStampUtc).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like LINQ works better with immutable objects. What about adding method to `Foo` called `RoundTimeStamp` that returns a new `Foo` with the time stamp rounded? Then it's just a simple `Select`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
var result =
    testData
        .GroupBy(otd => otd.TimeStampUtc.AddMilliseconds(-otd.TimeStampUtc.Millisecond))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
        .ToList();
```

From your source data, I get:

[image: results]

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this LINQ query:

```
var result = testData
    .Select(td => new Foo
    {
        TimeStampUtc = td.TimeStampUtc.AddMilliseconds(-td.TimeStampUtc.Millisecond),
        SomeData = td.SomeData
    })
    .OrderBy(td => td.TimeStampUtc)
    .DistinctBy(otd => otd.TimeStampUtc)
    .ToList();
```

Since we want the final collection to be sorted, putting the `OrderBy` last here is a good idea. Also sorting on the the unique values returned from `DistinctBy` instead of all the items will yield better performance for larger sets. There is also no guarantee that `DistinctBy` will return items in order, so sorting last is a good idea. Following the SELECT, DISTINCT and ORDERBY order of statements is recommended with SQL queries anyways, so applying the same logic to LINQ makes sense.